# How to create a CDK trigger using an existing lambda function

Tags: typescript, function, lambda, triggers, ncurses-cdk

I want a CDK after-deployment trigger. Triggers seem to be limited to lambda functions.  I have an existing lambda function I'd like to use. I'm using typescript.

The triggers constructor which expects `TriggerProps` which expects a `Function` instead of something matching `IFunction`.  This seems like a flaw/bug in the code?

My desired code is this:

```
const existingLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(
  this,
  "myExistingLambdaID",
  "arn:aws:lambda:us-xxx-1:##########:function:myFunctionName"
);


const ciTrigger = new triggers.Trigger(this, 'MyTrigger', {
  handler: existingLambda,
});
```

However, this rejects with

```
Type 'IFunction' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': currentVersion, runtime, canCreatePermissions, _layers, and 37 more.ts(2740)
```

Is there another CDK native way to achieve this? (i don't want to do this in bash, etc)